# Different results when invoking a python script from the command line or in the web server

Tags: python, forms, cgi

I am writing a python script to run on a apache web server. My first goal is to list the network interfaces that are available and, after, for each one, build a form to input some parameters of interest. My problem is that when I run the following script from the command line I get the expected result (a formatted html web page with form(s)) while if I assess it from the web, i.e. putting the script in my web server and remotely access it through `http://myipaddr/cgi-bin/myscript.py`, I get only the submission button and not the form(s).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# import required modules
import re
import cgi
from subprocess import *

var=Popen("ifconfig", stdout=PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()
result = re.findall("wlan[1-9]", var)

def DisplayForm():

    HTMLFormL1= '\n\nInterface:<BR> <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="interface%d" size=60><BR>\n'
    HTMLFormL2= 'Number of packets to send:<BR> <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="npackets%d" size=60><BR>\n'
    HTMLFormL3= 'Transmission channel:<BR> <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="channel%d" size=60><BR>\n'
    HTMLFormL4= 'Sleep time in usec:<BR> <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="sleeptime%d" size=60><BR><BR><BR>\n'

    HTMLForm = HTMLFormL1 + HTMLFormL2 + HTMLFormL3 + HTMLFormL4

    HTMLStart = '<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="caos.py">\n<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="key" VALUE="process">\n'

    for num in range(len(result)):
        HTMLForm_idx = HTMLForm % (num, num, num, num)
        HTMLStart = "%s%s" % (HTMLStart, HTMLForm_idx)

    HTMLBody = HTMLStart + '\n<BR><P><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Configure">\n</FORM>\n'

    print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
    HTMLHeader ='<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">\n<html>\n<head>\n<META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="blah blah -- your ad here">\n<title>CAOS</title>\n</head>\n<body>'
    HTMLFooter ='</body>\n</html>'
    print HTMLHeader
    print HTMLBody
    print HTMLFooter


#--- Begin of "main"
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
try:
    key = form["key"].value
except:
    key = None
if key != "process":
    DisplayForm()
```

I have looked for a similar problem, but I could not find anything similar on the web. Most likely I'm doing something stupid, but I cannot figure it out myself. I would very happy if someone could point me the right direction.

Cheers,
bman

Comment: Check your web server error logs to see whether you're getting any Python runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

Probably different versions of python are being run.
Check if your ssh user and web server user (www) is running same python from same path.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out `Popen` and replace `result` with mock values.  If Popen is causing the problem (as I suspect), you probably will want to obtain the values in a different manner than through an stdout pipe.